# Bulk create a primary object and objects referencing the primary object at the same time?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    pass

class Experience(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
```

How would I save a a Profile along with a list of Experiences with a single transaction?

Right now I'm doing the following

```
p = Profile()
p.save()

e_list = [Experience(profile=p), Experience(profile=p)]
Education.objects.bulk_create(e_list)
```

Which is two database hits, can I do it in one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transaction.atomic` in order to have multiple queries in the same transaction:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    p = Profile()
    p.save()

    e_list = [Experience(profile=p), Experience(profile=p)]
    Education.objects.bulk_create(e_list)
```

Comment: Does this process hit once really? How does it decide for profile withouth save before profile, I am confused. I'm very thankful if you explain it.

Comment: it's not the same query, but it's the same transaction. So if something goes wrong with an Education, everything will be rollbacked

Comment: I was answering "How would I save a a Profile along with a list of Experiences with a single transaction?". So this can be in same transaction, but you cannot do only 1 query for multiple table inserts.